# How to install Bento4 tools on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

have tried all the methods mentioned in the readme of https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4

Some of the methods showed some installing/making processes and some other methods showed errors! (make/cmake shows an installing process...scons method doesn't seem to work.)

My goal is to being able to run mp4decrypt from any directory in my Ubuntu-20.04

But it doesn't seems to work when I enter the command mp4decrypt.( Any other tools doesn't work too!). It doesn't seem to recognize the commands!

I am a beginner and I am a little new to these things. So any help on this would be highly valuable to me and I would be really grateful if anyone can help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Install Bento4 tools

```
git clone https://github.com/axiomatic-systems/Bento4.git
cd Bento4/
```

The file README.md, line 82, "Linux and other platforms, using CMake" :

```
mkdir cmakebuild
cd cmakebuild/
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
```

Install the executable to `/usr/local/bin/`, i.e. a system PATH : `sudo make install`, which means you can use the 26 tools from any location in the OS.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! I didn't know that I should put it in /usr/local/bin/ before! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `mp4dash`, `mp4hls`, `mp4dashclone` which are just bash wrappers to call python scripts like `mp4-dash.py`, you can move these directories as well.

```
cp -r ../Source/Python/utils /usr/local/bin
cp -r ../Source/Python/wrappers /usr/local/bin
```

The binstubs depend on relative paths so it's a lot less painful to bring them over as well. Add the wrappers directory to your path to use them like the other compiled executables.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/wrappers:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download binaries from http://www.bento4.com/downloads/

Unzip them and copy the contents of the bin folder into /usr/bin/local.

Eg. With the current version:

```sh
    wget https://www.bok.net/Bento4/binaries/Bento4-SDK-1-6-0-640.x86_64-unknown-linux.zip
    unzip Bento4-SDK-1-6-0-640.x86_64-unknown-linux.zip
    mv Bento4-SDK-1-6-0-640.x86_64-unknown-linux/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```